# Grouping linq to XML multiple hierarchies

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a list of students in a xml file (student.xml) as such :

```
           <root>
             <row>
               <school>AAAA </school>
               <grade> G1</grade>
               <student_name>xxx</student_name>
             </row>
             <row>
               <school>AAAA </school>
               <grade> G1</grade>
               <student_name>yyy</student_name>
             </row>
            <row>
               <school>AAAA </school>
               <grade> G2</grade>
               <student_name>zzz</student_name>
            </row>
            <row>
               <school>BBB</school>
               <grade> Gr1</grade>
               <student_name>sss</student_name>
            </row>
            <row>
               <school>BBB</school>
               <grade> Gr1</grade>
               <student_name>ttt</student_name>
            </row>
         </root>
```

I'm want to group all the students by the same school by the same grade using linq and save it in  groupStudent.xml

Expected Result (groupStudent.xml)

```
               <root>
                  <row>
                     <school>AAAA </school>
                     <grade> G1</grade>
                     <students>
                       <student_name>xxx</student_name>
                       <student_name>yyy</student_name>
                     </students>
                   </row>
                   <row>
                      <school>AAAA </school>
                      <grade> G2</grade>
                      <students>
                         <student_name>zzz</student_name>
                      </students>
                   </row>
                   <row>
                      <school>BBBB</school>
                      <grade> Gr1</grade>
                      <students>
                        <student_name>sss</student_name>
                        <student_name>ttt</student_name>
                     </students>
                </row>
              </root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed in this way (where `PathOld` is the path of your existing xml and `PathNew` where you want to save the new one)

```
        XDocument oldDoc = XDocument.Load(PathOld);

        var stGroup = oldDoc.Descendants("row").GroupBy(row =>
             new { s = row.Descendants("school").First().Value, g = row.Descendants("grade").First().Value },
             (key, gr) => new { key, list = gr}
             );


        XDocument newDoc = new XDocument();

        var root = new XElement("root");

        foreach (var item in stGroup)
        {
            var row = new XElement("row");
            row.Add(new XElement("school", item.key.s));
            row.Add(new XElement("grade", item.key.g));
            var stds = new XElement("students");
            foreach (var stud in item.list)
            {
                stds.Add(new XElement("student_name",
                    stud.Descendants("student_name").First().Value));
            }
            row.Add(stds);
            root.Add(row);
        }
        newDoc.Add(root);

        newDoc.Save(PathNew);
```